# Origin of the Shankara legend?

Tags: puranas, culture, adi-shankaracharya

The film *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom* is based on a lot of lurid and sensationalist stereotypes about worshippers of Maa Kali and Sri Shiva. However, the central plot conceit is based around a supposed legend of "Shankara", who met Sri Shiva on top of a mountain and received five stones to assist him spreading dharma throughout the world. These were subsequently referred to as "Shankara stones".

Though fictional, is this based on an actual story or text? Presumably, "Shankara" is referring to Sri Adi Shankaracharya, who (I have heard) did encounter manifestations of Sri Shiva during his travels across India. If so, please provide a citation of the relevant texts.

Comment: Your asking for references for a fictional movie? Pure fiction. There was nothing in the movie that had anything to do with Hinduism. Vote to close.

Comment: Legend has it that Adi Sankara did visit Sri Shiva in Kailasa and was gifted with sphatika / atma lingas which he placed in the Sankara peethas. He also received Ananda Lahari/Soundarya Lahari upadesam.